# How to animate drawing polyline repeatedly with raphael.js

Tags: javascript, animation, raphael

I know there are several questions connected with raphael and js animating, but I couldn't find any help there. I'm completly new to js and I would appreciate your help.

I want to animate some words (drawing them with paths) with raphael. I want to draw a word, remove it and draw another word, etc. So f.e. I want to draw (animate) word "CAT", clear it, then animate word "MAN", clear it, animate word "DOG", clear it and animate CAT again and then MAN and so on.

I have two codes that are doing the things that I want to do, but I cannot combine them. I would appreciate if you told me how to use them together or maybe there is some other way to do the task I want to do.

1. This one draws a letter using animate and specyfing the lines

   ```
   <html>
       <head>
       <script src="raphael-min.js"></script>

       <script> 
           var c= Raphael("canvas", 200, 200);
           var p = c.path("M140 100");
           var r = c.path("M165 60");
           var s = c.path("M153 80");
           p.animate({path:"M140 100 L165 60"}, 2000, function() {
                   r.animate({path: "M165 60 L190 100"}, 2000, function() {
                       s.animate({path: "M153 80 L178 80"}, 2000);
                   });
           });
       };
       </script>
   </head>
   <body>
       <div id="canvas"></div>
   </body>
   ```
2. This one animates a line and reapeats it

   ```
   <html>
   <head>
       <style>
       #icon {
           width: 500px;
           height: 500xp;
       }
   </style>

   <script src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
   <script src="raphael-min.js"></script>
   <script>
       $(document).ready(function() {
           var paper = Raphael("icon", 500, 500);
           var path = paper.path("M 140 100");

           var anim = Raphael.animation({path : "M 100 100 400 400"}, 1000).repeat(Infinity);
           path.animate(anim);         
       });
   </script>
   </head>
   <body>
       <div id="icon"></div>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```

Comment: can you post Some HTML here so we can help you quick

Comment: @Prog, I edited the code to show the whole HTML I'm using.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you managed to animate the letters and your problem is just animating one after another.

You should draw the animations inside sets, I believe it is the best way to draw and redraw inside the same container, using remove (it wont work with simple variables).

```
var c= Raphael("canvas");
function a() {
  c.setStart();
  p = c.path("M140 100").attr({stroke: "#000"});
  r = c.path("M165 60").attr({stroke: "#000"});
  s = c.path("M153 80").attr({stroke: "#000"});
  p.animate({path:"M140 100 L165 60"}, 2000, function() {
    r.animate({path: "M165 60 L190 100"}, 2000, function() {
      s.animate({path: "M153 80 L178 80"}, 2000);
    });
  });
  cat = c.setFinish();
};
a();
setInterval(function() {
  cat.remove();
  a();
}, 10000);
```

One way to call a function after another function is using setInterval but this part I am not sure if it is the best.